# Need Interpretation of 64bit Assembly Instruction As Opposed to 32bit

Tags: assembly, x86, 32bit-64bit, disassembly, att

I am going through the book Hacking : The Art of Exploitation which uses 32bit assembly, and my machine is 64 bit. Now I understand that's not a great thing, but this is the question.

As I debug this program,

```
  Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x113d: file first.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/kingvon/Desktop/asm/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at first.c:6
6               for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
(gdb) x/3i $rip
=> 0x55555555513d <main+8>:     movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x555555555144 <main+15>:    jmp    0x555555555156 <main+33>
   0x555555555146 <main+17>:    lea    0xeb7(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555556004
```

this is what I see on my machine(64 bit),

```
0x55555555513d <main+8>:     movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
```

but in the example(32 bit) given it says:

```
0x55555555513d <main+8>:     mov   DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0x0
```

From reading the 32 bit assembly it is quite clear that this should mean that the machine will move the value of 0 into memory location stored in the EBP register minus 4. I am aware both instructions do the same things, but I feel the 64 instruction does not look like what it really means. How can the 64 instruction interpreted/worded? I am aware that the register names are different on 64 bit

Comment: The main difference between the two instructions you’ve shown is not because one is 32 bit and one is 64 bit, but that one is AT&T syntax and one is Intel syntax. The operands are reversed and the percent signs, dollar signs, and the words “dword ptr” are distinguishing features.

Comment: @prl Book also states to set to intel which I have done, but gdb stays at&t... I've tried `echo "set disassembly-flavor intel" > ~/.gdbinit` and checked file, which says it is set to intel, but gdb keeps printing in at&t..... edit - typo in .gdbinit, gdb now prints in intel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably easiest to just build 32-bit executables so you can follow the book more closely, with `gcc -m32`.  Don't try to port a tutorial to another OS or ISA while you're learning from it, that rarely goes well.  (e.g. different calling conventions, not just different sizes.)

And in GDB, use `set disassembly-flavor intel` to get GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` disassembly like your book shows, instead of the default AT&T syntax.  For objdump, use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for more about looking at GCC ouptut.

(See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info vs. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel_syntax/info).

**Both instructions are a dword store of an immediate 0, to an offset of -4 relative to where the frame pointer is pointing.**  (This is how it implements `i=0` because you compiled with optimization disabled.)

Comment: I've tried -m32, but gcc spits out `/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>`.

Comment: @raincouver: so install your distro's `gcc-multilib` package or whatever it calls it, like Arch's `lib32-gcc-libs`.  (Without it, you can build and link pure asm static executable where you write your own `_start` and don't link any libraries, but everything else will need `/usr/lib32/libc.so` and so on, and yeah the 32-bit headers to even compile.)

Comment: I have set gdb to intel and edited .gdbinit to intel but gdb just won't change to intel. Edit- I have made a typo in .gdbinit, problem is now fixed